# jquery uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slider'

Tags: jquery, slider, range

Hi I want jQuery to be able to read the URL that is inserted and if it is a value that is defined I want it to load in different content:

I've used the below code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
    var slider = $('#year_range');

          if(window.location.href.indexOf("#digitl2004")) {
       // hide elements
        $('#year_range').slider('value', 2004);
      }
      });
 </script>
```

But I keep getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slider'`

Not sure why this is occurring, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is supposed to be slider() method? Include corresponding plugin

Comment: Why are you binding $('#year_range') and don't use it 3 lines after ? .slider() is a jqueryUI method, did you include it right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you are trying to call the "slider" method on a jquery object. but jquery itself does not contain a definition for this method. maybe you are missing a plugin?